# How to add RDLC report inside a asp.net core project and pass data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I have an old .net framework project. Now I am trying to convert that project to asp .net core. I have several RDLC report inside the old project. Now I want to use those reports inside my new asp.net core project.

**Query:**

1. How do I use the RDLC report inside asp.net core?
2. Do I need to create new RDLC report or I can use my old RDLC report?
3. How can I pass data from ASP.Net core controller to RDLC report?

Comment: Avoid asking multiple questions (it could be flagged as too broad and closed)